# Non-Greedy Single Character Match Regex

Tags: regex

I'm doing a non-greedy match like this

```
'(?<C2>.+?)'
```

to find a group inside a quotes. This works well, until I want to do something like this

```
'(?<C2>.+?)' as
```

to match something in quotes followed by a space, following by the word as.

But now, the following will not match as desired

```
'hello'123'hello2' as
```

I want this to not match at all...but it ends up matching the whole chunk

```
'hello'123'hello2'
```

as `C2`

What's the best way to force the non-greedy `.+?` to include up to the first occurance of a `'`, not the first occurance of `' as`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work

```
(?<C2>'[^']+')(?= as)
```

Explanation

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?<C2>                   group and capture to C2:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    '                        '\''
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^']+                    any character except: ''' (1 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    '                        '\''
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     as                      ' as'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```

Even without the lookahead `(?= as)`, `(?<C2>'[^']+')` will match quoted strings in a non-greedy way as expected.

Comment: That makes the group match correctly...but how can I make the whole regex match fail?

Answer (score 2):

You can try;

```
'(?<C2>[^']+?)' as
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I understood your question differently than those who have replied so far. By

> What's the best way to force the non-greedy .+? to include up to the first occurance of a ', not the first occurance of ' as

did you mean to say you wanted to match the word between the first two `'`, i.e. `hello`, not `hello2`? In that case, this is my suggestion:

```
'(?<C2>.+?)'(?! as)
```

The negative lookahead will ensure that you will not match the word which comes before `as`.

In case I misunderstood your request: sorry.